# nested lambda function , TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'function'

Tags: python-3.x, lambda

Following piece of code gives error while calling

```
a = lambda x : x +( lambda y : y * 30)

--call
a(1)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#334>", line 1, in <module>
    a(1)
  File "<pyshell#330>", line 1, in <lambda>
    a = lambda x : x +( lambda y : y * 30)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'function'
```

Is there a way to achieve this using nested lambda

Comment: What on Earth are you trying to achieve? What output are you expecting? The code as written is nonsense, so you need to indicate the expected behavior; we can't guess any more than the compiler here.

Comment: So you want to do `(x, y) -> x + (y * 30)`?

Comment: Code which doesn't do what you want is often an extremely poor way of explaining what you *do* want.  I hope I have managed to guess your intentions correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat torturedly, something like this?

```
a = lambda x: 1 + (lambda y: y*30)(x)
```

If you create and name `lambda y` outside of `lambda x`, it's somewhat cleaner, but I guess you would call that cheating.

```
f = lambda y: y*30
a = lambda x: x + f(x)
```

Comment: Or, if they want to call with two arguments, something like this: `a = lambda x, y: x + (lambda y: y * 30)(y)`. Then call like `a(x, y)`?

Comment: The OP's example shows passing just one argument, so I guess that would be passed to `lambda y` as well, but we are obviously both guessing.  Thanks for your example; I simplified mine a lot thanks to that.